# If $H \le K \le G$ then $H \trianglelefteq \overline{K}$?

Tags: topological-groups

If I have topological groups $H \le K \le  G$, I could prove that if $H \trianglelefteq K$ then $\overline{H} \trianglelefteq K$ but is it also true that $H \trianglelefteq \overline{K}$?

Comment: You consider closures in $G$ or in $\bar G$?

Comment: closures in G I guess

Comment: What do you mean by "I guess"?

Comment: $G$ is the topological group I consider (with subgroups $H$ and $K$). So I thought $G$ is closed and open so $\overline{G}=G$

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then it is normal in any intermediate subgroup $K'$, since it is closed under conjugation by any element $g\in K'$.
In particular, this holds for $K'=\bar K$.

So, the following statements are true in this case:
$$H\trianglelefteq K,\quad H\trianglelefteq \bar K,\quad 
\bar H\trianglelefteq \bar K\,.$$
However, the forth statement, $\bar H\trianglelefteq K$ only holds if $\bar H\subseteq K$, which is *not guaranteed* in general, for example if $K$ is assumed to be *closed*.

Comment: Thank you. While reading your answer I realised I made a typo in the question. It should be $H \trianglelefteq K$ then $\overline{H} \trianglelefteq K$ (as you point out, provided $\overline{H}\subset K$)

Comment: Ok, then your solution is probably fine. I think also in this case $H\trianflelefteteq\bar K$ follows, though that's a different question.